# Kendo scrolling listview not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am trying to scroll a list view to the top when a button is clicked, however it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is an example...

http://jsbin.com/jofijowa/1/edit

Essentially, I am trying to move the list view like this...

```
  function scrollTop() {
    console.log("Hello World"); //debug
    var scroller = $("#flat-listview").kendoMobileScroller()
    console.log(scroller); //debug
    scroller.scrollTop(0);
  }
```

#flat-listview being the id of the ul

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Mobile Scroller uses scrollTop only when the View has native scrolling enabled. When it isn't - it uses CSS transforms for scrolling instead. If you use the [reset method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/scroller#methods-reset) of the scroller, it will scroll to the top regardless of the current scrolling type.